# Best way to refactor this without making as many calls as I am?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, activerecord, refactoring

I am trying to cycle through a few of these blocks. They basically narrow down a number of people that fulfill a bunch of attributes.

I apologize if this seems really messy, but my database is really taking a toll processing this, and I know there's a better way. I'm just lost on strategy right now.

**My Code:**

def count_of_distribution

```
#beginning with an array..
array_of_users = []

# any matching zip codes? ..
# zip_codes
@zip_codes = self.distributions.map(&:zip_code).compact
unless @zip_codes.nil? || @zip_codes.empty? 
  @matched_zips = CardSignup.all.map(&:zip_code) & @zip_codes
  @matched_zips.each do |mz| 
    CardSignup.find(:all, :conditions => ["zip_code = ?", mz]).each do |cs|
     array_of_users << cs.id
    end
  end
end

# any matching interests?..
# interest
@topics = self.distributions.map(&:me_topic).compact
unless  @topics.nil? || @topics.empty?
  @matched_topics = MeTopic.all.map(&:name) & @topics
  @matched_topics.each do |mt|
    MeTopic.find(:all, :conditions => ["name = ?", mt]).each do |mt2|
      mt2.users.each do |u|
        array_of_users << u.card_signup.id if u.card_signup
      end
    end
  end
end

# any matching sexes?..
# sex
@sexes = self.distributions.map(&:sex).compact
unless @sexes.nil? || @sexes.empty?
  @matched_sexes = CardSignup.all.map(&:sex) & @sexes
  @matched_sexes.each do |ms|
    CardSignup.find(:all, :conditions => ["sex = ?", ms]).each do |cs|
      array_of_users << cs.id
    end
  end
end

  total_number = array_of_users.compact.uniq

  return total_number
end
```

This is the most embarressing results ever :

```
Completed in 51801ms (View: 43903, DB: 7623) | 200 OK [http://localhost/admin/emails/3/distributions/new]
```

**UPDATED ANSWER** It is truncated but still takes a huge toll on the DB

```
  array_of_users = []

  @zip_codes = self.distributions.map(&:zip_code).compact
  @sexes = self.distributions.map(&:sex).compact

  @zips_and_sexes = CardSignup.find(:all, :conditions => ["gender IN (?) OR zip_code IN (?)", my_sexes, my_zips])
  @zips_and_sexes.each{|cs| array_of_users << cs.id }

  @topics = self.distributions.map(&:me_topic).compact
  @all_topics = MeTopic.find(:all, :conditions => ["name IN (?)", @topics])
  array_of_users << CardSignup.find(:all, :conditions => ["user_id IN (?)", @all_topics.map(&:users)]).map(&:id)
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/, no?

Comment: Oh cool, never heard of that! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is. It runs super fast now :

```
array_of_users = []

# zips and sexes
@zip_codes = self.distributions.map(&:zip_code).compact
@sexes = self.distributions.map(&:sex).compact
@zips_and_sexes = CardSignup.find(:all, :conditions => ["gender IN (?) OR zip_code IN (?)", @sexes, @zip_codes])
@zips_and_sexes.each{|cs| array_of_users << cs.id }

# interest
@topics = self.distributions.map(&:me_topic).compact
@selected_topics = MeTopic.find(:all, :conditions => ["name in (?)", @topics]).map(&:id)
@matched_users = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT * FROM `me_topics_users` WHERE (me_topic_id IN ('#{@selected_topics.join("', '")}') )")
@list_of_user_ids = []
@matched_users.each{|a| @list_of_user_ids << a[0] }
@list_of_user_ids.uniq!
array_of_users << CardSignup.find(:all, :conditions => ["user_id IN (?)", @list_of_user_ids]).map(&:id)

# age
@ages = self.distributions.map(&:age).compact
@ages_array = []
@ages.each{|a| @ages_array << how_old(a) }
@ages_array.each{|aa| array_of_users << aa.id}

array_of_users << CardSignup.all.map(&:id) if array_of_users.flatten.empty?
total_number = array_of_users.flatten.uniq

return total_number
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to let rails do all the computation through series of loops; no wonder it's taking so long.

It's hard to follow, but perhaps instead of using `.each` loops, try to pull out everything you are after right away, and then use a `.group_by(&:attribute)`

OR if your end result is just card signups.

It seems you are trying to get all the users that have something in desired, a zip, a topic, or sex. So, let the database do the work.

`my_zips = @zip_codes = self.distributions.map(&:zip_code).compact.join(", ")`
`my_sexes = @sexes = self.distributions.map(&:sex).compact.join(", ")`

`all_cards = CardSignup.find(:all, :conditions => ["sex IN (?) OR zip_code IN (?)", my_sexes, my_zips])`

`my_topics = @topics = self.distributions.map(&:me_topic).compact.join(", ")`
`all_topics = MeTopic.find(:all, :conditions => ["name = ?", my_topics])`

`more_cards = all_topics.map{|x| x.users}.map{|n| n.card_signup}`
`total_number = (all_cards + more_cards).flatten.uniq`

I hope this is a better answer.

Comment: How would the group_by save computation time?

Comment: What exactly is the end result you are looking for?

Comment: Distributions are selection of characteristics to send an email to. And when people sign up for the subscription, they choose their characteristics. I am trying to match up the characteristics chosen in the Distribution with the attributes in the CardSignups

Comment: @Trip You might get better results by posting your DB schema a bit of sample data, and the sort of query results you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Yeah, I think I'm missing what your after.

Comment: My apologies Ray301. If you're still interested, I'm basically matching a bunch of subscriptions ( CardSignups ) with a bunch of different types of emails ( Distributions ). That way people get sent what they're looking for. In my code above, I'm trying to narrow down the results to age, sex, interests, and zip code.

Comment: Hey amazing answer, btw. A Quick note, when you add `join(", ")` , it breaks it because its no longer an array for SQL to cycle through with `IN`

Comment: I updated my answer above with your supported answer, but it still takes the same toll on the DB.